# Have not been able to integrate InstallShield 2021 R2 with Visual Studio 2019 professional

Tags: installshield

We are evaluating InstallShield 2021 R2.
I installed the InstallShield before the VS 2019 Professional.
I can see my installer (.ism) project, but when clicked on it said "incompatible". I added it to the solution as an existing project. However, I do not get the build popup, when doing a right click on the installer project. There is also a plus next to the project showing "Pending Add."
I followed a procedure at https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/InstalllShield-2018-R2-installer-won-t-register-Visual-Studio/m-p/159052
Here I executed the the command shown at the following directory:
C:\Program Files(x86)\InstallShield\2020\System\TSConfig /registerVSIP
The command did not help. Please advise.
Thank you,
Ken

Comment: Don't buy InstallShield, it is dirty product and services. I request refund money but they don't refund. The license model is dirty, you cannot use InstallShield perpetual after end of subscription, and must buy 3 years of subscription. Don't buy.

Comment: Use open source will be better for money, like WiX 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am use InstallShield 2021 R2 Premier now.

InstallShield 2021 R2 has integration with every editions of Visual Studio 2019. But totally doesn't support Visual Studio 2022 any more.

(should not buy it)